# Python Reshape a list with odd number of elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list with an odd number of elements. I want to convert it into a specific size.

My code:

```
alist = ['a','b','c']
cols= 2
rows = int(len(alist)/cols)+1 # 2
anarray = np.array(alist.extend([np.nan]*((rows*cols)-len(months_list)))).reshape(rows,cols)
```

Present output:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (2,2)
```

Expected output:

```
anarray  = [['a','b'],['c',nan]]
```

Comment: `list.extend` does not return the object so you're effectively creating an array of `None`

Comment: if you get a problem like this in the future, I suggest breaking it into separate statements and seeing that each does what you expect it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
out = np.full((rows,cols), np.nan, dtype='object')

out.ravel()[:len(alist)] = alist
```

Output:

```
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['c', nan]], dtype=object)
```

As a side note, this might be better for you:

```
rows = int(np.ceil(len(alist)/cols))
```

Comment: That's right. Even I am worried about the rows. My code will unnecessarily add one when there is a even list. So, I should add one when there is odd, nothing when even.

Comment: I got error with `rows` as `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. It is giving `float`. How to convert it to `int`?

Comment: `np.nan` is float. I don't think numpy allow conversion of `np.nan` to `int`.

Comment: I got error because `rows = np.ceil(len(alist)/cols)` gives `2.0`. So, I should have `2` while reshaping it right?

Comment: ah, wrap it around `int`. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to achieve the result:

```
li = ['a','b','c']
l = len(li)

new_list = [li[x:x+2] for  x in range(l // 2)]
if l % 2 != 0:
    new_list.append([li[-1], None])
print(new_list) # [['a', 'b'], ['c', None]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try (without any external library)

```
import math

alist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
cols = 2
new_list = []
steps = math.ceil(len(alist) / cols)
start = 0
for x in range(0, steps):
    new_list.append(alist[x * cols: (x + 1) * cols])
new_list[-1].extend([None for t in range(cols - len(new_list[-1]))])
print(new_list)
```

output

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', None]]
```