# Struggling to reshape an odd array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am struggling with a problem from my python class that has been assigned where I have to create a 1D array with the `arange` function from 0 to 29. Then reshape it into:

1. An array of rank 2 of the appropriate size.
2. An array of rank 3 of the appropriate size.

I am able to create the array with `z = np.arange(29)`, however I am unable to reshape it to be a 2d/3d array.

```
z = np.arange(29)
print(z.shape)
z = z.reshape(2,14)
```

But then I get an error saying:

```
ValueError:cannot reshape array of size 29 into shape (2,14)
```

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question and explain what happened (if there is an error message show it in the question, too).

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you for the suggestion this is my first time using stack overflow and even though this is a class it self taught so I don't really have a strong understanding.

Comment: is it 29 exclusive? np.arange(29) will create an array of numbers from 0 to 28

Comment: @drake10k yes it is exclusive it will create an array from 0-28.

Comment: The error is saying that it cannot reshape the array because it has an odd number of elements (29), which is not divisible by 2.

Comment: @drake10k i know that is the problem i am struggling, i am trying to figure out how to make the odd amount into a 2d array

Comment: You cannot really do this with an odd number of elements. I presume the actual requirement is to have an array that contains the numbers from 0 to 28, but it doesn't necessarily have to be 29 in length. If this is the case you can add a nan element to make it 30 and then reshaping it should be fine.

Comment: @drake10k i believe you may be right if it is the 0-29 but just incase how would i include a nan element

Comment: x = np.arange(29)
x = np.append(x, np.nan) or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247398/python-reshape-a-list-with-odd-number-of-elements for another solution

Comment: @drake10k thanks for the help sorry if my questions were really dumb

Comment: What do you think is "odd" about the array?

Answer (score 1):

While the specification is a bit ambiguous, I suspect they want you to generate 30 numbers that include 0 and 29:

```
In [73]: arr = np.arange(30)
In [74]: arr
Out[74]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29])
In [75]: arr.shape
Out[75]: (30,)
```

There many ways you can reshape this, all of which assume 30 values:

```
In [76]: arr.reshape(2,15)
Out[76]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])

In [77]: arr.reshape(3,10)
Out[77]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])

In [79]: arr.reshape(2,3,5)
Out[79]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Proposed solution based on comments.**

Assumption is the that the array should include the numbers from 0 to 28, but it doesn't necessarily have to be of size 29. This allows us to add np.nan as the 30th element allowing the reshape.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(29)
x = np.append(x, np.nan)
print(x.shape)

y = x.reshape(15, 2)
print(y.shape)

z = x.reshape(5, 3, 2)
print(z.shape)
```

output:

```
(30,)
(15, 2)
(5, 3, 2)
```